# Stop webpage from auto-reload with selenium/chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Im using python with the selenium package and the chromedriver to scrape a webpage. The page is automatically reloading itself (probably via java-script) every 30 min, which destroyes my scraping-progress.

The webscraping is done with a script and the javascript ist needed for further interaction with the page.

Is it possible to stop the page from reloading itself, maybe with a flag for the chromedriver?

Comment: Can you share the URL? - you can use JS to stop the process but I'd need to see the page to create an answer for you

Comment: I cant disable JS from the beginning, because I need it to navigate through the page later.

Comment: How about a process:  1) Go to page 2) disable JS, 3) scrape what you want, 3) refresh the page to turn the JS back on `driver.refresh()` .... one line of code in the loop to solve your issue....?

Comment: That would be an option if its possible to stop JS after the webdriver is already initialized. The only way i found to stop JS is like this:

Comment: `chrome_options = Options()`
`chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-javascript")`
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a Solution myself. I had to execute the following dev-tools command with the webdriver:

`driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setScriptExecutionDisabled', {'value': True})`

Answer (score 1):

You can just open the DevTools and pause the Debugger. Works in Firefox and Chrome (tested)!