# Cannot scroll all the way down the page, because it keeps refreshing Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate saving website's description and url. I loop the program and come to the function `get_info()`. Basically it need to add the first website on the google page I load and scroll down so when it executes again it can add other websites. The problem is that the program refresh the page everytime it executes `get_info()` and brings you back at the top.

```python
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

browser=webdriver.Firefox()


def get_info():
    browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[2])
    description = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h3"))
    ).text

    site = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "cite"))
    )
    site.click()

    url=browser.current_url
    browser.back()

    browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,400)","")
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop Chrome from auto-reloading , you can do this

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Emulation.setScriptExecutionDisabled', {'value': True})
```

Link to read about this Chrome Devtools flag - [here](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Emulation/#method-setScriptExecutionDisabled)

The question already has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64817185/stop-webpage-from-auto-reload-with-selenium-chromedriver)

Comment: is there a solution for Firefox?